# Object not instantiated at OnDeserialized

Tags: c#, deserialization

I have two classes:

```
[Serializable]
class AddressBook {

    private Dictionary<string, Address> entries = new Dictionary<string, Address>();

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void EnsureValid(StreamingContext context) {
        // make sure each entry has a non-whitespace name and non-null address
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Address {
    private Dictionary<string, string> elements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public IReadOnlyList<string> StandardElements { get; } = new List<string> { "street", "city", "state", "zip" };

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void EnsureValid(StreamingContext context) {
        foreach (var standardElement in StandardElements) {
            if (!elements.ContainsKey(standardElement) || elements[standardElement] == null) {
                elements[standardElement] = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my deserialization code:

```
public AddressBook Load() {
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (var input = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        return (AddressBook)formatter.Deserialize(input);
    }
}
```

`AddressBook` deserializes fine, but when an `Address` instance included in `AddressBook`'s `entries` field deserializes and `Address.EnsureValid()` runs `elements` is `null`. I would have thought that the object instance would be fully created when the `OnDeserialized` method runs. Am I missing something?

If I comment out `[OnDeserialized]` in `Address.EnsureValid()` everything works OK. However, I need that method to run at some point.

Comment: Duplicate?  [Dictionary is empty on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25582842/3744182).

Comment: Almost a duplicate. I implemented the `IDeserializationCallback` interface on my class, but I still have the problem. In my case, the `Dictionary` is null, so I can't call its `OnDeserialization()` method.

Comment: In that case can you [edit] your question and provide a full [mcve] demonstrating the problem with the `Address` class?  The `Dictionary<string, string> elements` seems like it never has non-default values so I don't see how it gets filled.

Comment: I omitted the constructors...that's where elements was getting filled. That being said, it's now working using the `IDeserializationCallback` and `OnDeserialization()` approach. I don't know what I changed, but it must have been something. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Mark as a duplicate then?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm happy to do it, or if easier I'm happy for you to do it.