# C# Deserializing dictionary contains proper keys but null values

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have a class that implements `ISerializable` and stores a `Dictionary` which holds objects. These objects have multiple levels of child objects that also contain collections and various other fields that are all serializable as well.

In unit testing, everything serializes and deserializes just fine when testing the underlying child objects, but in this outermost class, when I deserialize the `Dictionary` that contains all child elements (and all of their children, and so on), the keys load properly, but all of the values associated with the keys are `null`.

Here is how the outermost class looks:

```
[Serializable]
internal class ChildCollection : ISerializable
{
  private readonly Dictionary<ulong, ChildElement> _children;

  protected ChildCollection( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
  {
    _childElements = new Dictionary<ulong, ChildElement>();

    var children = ( Dictionary<ulong, ChildElement> )info.GetValue( nameof( _children ), typeof( Dictionary<ulong, ChildElement> ) );
    children.OnDeserialization( null );

    foreach( var child in children.Values )
      Add( child ); // This throws an exception, as all values are null
  }

  public virtual void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
  {
    info.AddValue( nameof( _children ), _children );
  }
}
```

I understand that C# Serialization is very messy in terms of how it's implemented, and that `OnDeserialization` needs to be called on the dictionary in order to load values. What I don't understand is that I have this exact same implementation for another class (although that class has simpler child elements). I also don't understand why serialization works at every level until this class.

Comment: Related: [Dictionary is empty on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25582842/3744182).  To say if it's a duplicate I think we would need to see a [mcve].  The recommendation there is to do the postprocessing in the `OnDeserialization()` method of `ChildCollection`.

Comment: Why mess with this type of serialization when JSON.NET can serialize dictionaries? If you want a compact binary format, you could also do BSON...